# How to add gradle project dependency into another gradle project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, monorepo

I have one Monorepo of Gradle Project and have the below structure with 1 gradle application `archive-api` and 1 gradle library `transcript-xml-parser`.

[image: project structure]

I want to add `transcript-xml-parser` library dependency into `archive-api` application. Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Below is my `build.gradle` file for `transcript-xml-parser` gradle library:

```
 plugins {
    id("java")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    implementation("org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1")
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
        name "<artifactory-name>"
        url "<jfrog-repository-url>"
        credentials {
            username = username
            password = password
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the below line in `archive-api` app `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation project(':projects:library:transcript-xml-parser')
```

Above line will add `transcript-xml-parser` as a dependency in `archive-api` app. But for this to make it work we need to make sure that `transcript-xml-parser` library should build first and the artifact should be available before `archive-api` app builds.

Hence, in the parent `settings.gradle` file we need to add as follows:

```
include("projects:application:archive-api")
include("projects:library:transcript-xml-parser")
```

We need to make sure `archive-api` app should define first than `transcript-xml-parser` library in `settings.gradle` file to tell **GRADLE** the sequence of build.